# Why I can't add a new item from a CSV file into an array inside a while loop in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, csv

I want to generate a jSON string with some data imported from a csv file using PHP and adding that later into a mySQL database field.

I want to take information that is already inside the database field, and update it with the information that I'm importing from the csv file.

The data imported are comments to each post that is already in the database. The comments are inserted into the table field in jSON format. What I want is to add all comments (in the csv file) line by line.

Here's my forum table:

```
CREATE TABLE foro (
    foroID int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    userID int(11) NOT NULL,
    deprecated_nodeID int(11) NULL,
    datosPost text null //THIS IS THE FIELD IN JSON FORMAT
)
```

The deprecated node ID is the post ID from the older site that I'm taking the information to be imported from.

**This is some sample data from the csv file:**
This is the format when I insert each line into an array:

```
array(5) { 
    [0]=> string(3) "deprecated_nodeID" 
    [1]=> string(16) "commentTitle" 
    [2]=> string(9) "date" 
    [3]=> string(16) "userID" 
    [4]=> string(10) "comment" 
}
```

> "9193","Mabel de acuerdo a mis","13.02.2017 16:54:37","21222","En caso
>   de que se quieran ejecutar más de dos y el demandado paga. Saludos"
>
> "9193","Según el material","01.03.2017 17:03:10","24970","Según el
>   material suministrado"
>
> "9193","Lo Planteo en clase","02.03.2017 09:03:22","21222","Hay una
>   incongruencia entre el material y lo que se dio en clase, gracias
>   Marcela"
>
> "9191","Hola Mabel, del Administrador","13.02.2017
>   16:48:51","21222","El Administrador no tiene horarios no es un
>   empleado en relación de dependencia, esta brindando un Servicio."
>
> "9168","La consignación  se realiza","13.02.2017
>   17:03:19","21222","Mediante  el  depósito  ante  un  escribano  de 
>   registro,  a  nombre de la persona."

As you can see, the first three lines in the csv file correspond to comments of the same nodeID, so they all should be inserted into the same field.

**This is what I am doing in order to do that, and my problem is that even if I'm inside the while loop, I can't get the new array elements to be all inserted, because the new elements overwrites the older ones.**

Please note that I've still haven't converted the output to jSON, it's still in array format, and I'm stuck there at the moment, because of the loop problem.

```
if (($handle = fopen("importar.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $conectar = new PDO('mysql:host='.HOST.'; dbname='.DATABASE.'; charset=utf8', USER, PASS); 

        $deprecated_nodeID = $data[0];

        $importarNodo = $conectar->prepare('
            SELECT deprecated_nodeID, datosPost FROM foro
            WHERE deprecated_nodeID = ?
            ');
            $importarNodo->bindParam(1, $deprecated_nodeID);
            $ok = $importarNodo->execute();
//HERE I GET THE NODE TO BE UPDATED LATER WITH THE NEW INFORMATION.
//THE FIELD THAT SHOULD BE UPDATED LATER IS datosPost THAT IT ALREADY HAS SOME INFORMATION.
            $x = $importarNodo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);            

            $datosPost = json_decode($x['datosPost'], TRUE);
```

If I do var_dump($datosPost), I get this format:

```
array(3) { 
    ["fecha"]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> int(1158019156) 
    } 
    ["autor"]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> string(1) "1" 
    } 
    ["mensaje"]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> string(160) "Si se dispone que el pago de las expensas" 
    } 
}

//IF THE NODE ID IS THE SAME AS THE NODE ID OF THE CSV LINE
//THEN PROCEED TO ADD A NEW ITEM TO THE ARRAY
            if ($x['deprecated_nodeID'] == $data[0]) {

                $datosPost['fecha'][] = obtenerUnixTime($data[2]);
                $datosPost['autor'][] = $data[3];
                $datosPost['mensaje'][] = $data[4];
```

The intended output after added all the new information is this:

```
array(3) { 
    ["fecha"]=> array(1) { //date of first post and each comment
        [0]=> int(1158019156)
        [1]=> int(1158019654) 
        [2]=> int(1158749156) 
        [3]=> int(6548019156) 
        ...
    } 
    ["autor"]=> array(1) { //author user ID
        [0]=> string(1) "1" 
        [1]=> string(1) "58" 
        [2]=> string(1) "23" 
        [3]=> string(1) "5" 
        ...
    } 
    ["mensaje"]=> array(1) { //first post and later comments
        [0]=> string(160) "Si se dispone que el pago de las expensas" 
        [1]=> string(160) "Banco a la orden del Consorcio" 
        [2]=> string(160) "el ticket del Banco sirve" 
        [3]=> string(160) "como recibo de expensas?" 
    } 
}

...
```

What I'm getting is just one comment added (I get in each case the `[0]` and `[1]`), as if it were overwritten in each passing of the loop, or the loop is not working?

*I tried using `array_push()` instead of adding a new item using `$datosPost['fecha'][]` and so on, but the result is the same.*

Comment: Add limit 0,100 at the end of your sql and change fetch to fetchall. Change limit accordingly.

Comment: *"The comments are inserted into the table field in jSON format."* - what happens when you need to delete a single comment? Wouldn't it be better to have a separate `comment` table?

Comment: if you want to output a json you should try `json_encode` instead of `json_decode`

Comment: `while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) { $conectar = new PDO('mysql:host='.HOST.'; dbname='.DATABASE.'; charset=utf8', USER, PASS);` ... why are you creating a new connector for each iteration of the loop?

Comment: @Nitin it just fetches one item in the database, as the nodeID is unique.

Comment: @CD001 I don't want to add that functionality, but maybe it would make the import easier... and you're right, I should put the connector outside of the loop!

Comment: @Taki I'm not converting to json yet, just taking the json string from the database and trying to add at the end of it each comment.

Comment: Can you show array you want to get finally?

Comment: Apart from the couple of issues I mentioned, unless I'm missing something else, this really does look like it should work... :\

Comment: How about adding a fresh new array at start $new = []; i think you are rewriting the var $datosPost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `$datosPost` is overwritten inside the `while` loop in every iteration, try adding an array at the begining of your code like `$myArr = array();` and after you fill `$datosPost` add it to `$myArr` with `array_push($myArr, $datosPost)` ( you can do this after the `if` statement,

also try `var_dump($datosPost );` inside the `while` loop to see if it's actually getting updated,

you can add `echo 'here';` inside `if ($x['deprecated_nodeID'] == $data[0])` to see if your code actually gets into the `if` statement,